# MarkLogic 8 - XQuery - How to do cts:element-value-query partial match

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Say I have:

`<location>Houston, TX</location>`

I can easily do:

`cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("location"), "Houston, TX")`

But how can I easily do:
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("location"), "*TX*")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is `cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("location"), "TX")` to match on the word rather than a wildcard.  There's ways to do wildcards, but that's not needed here.

Comment: Thank you! There are so many ways to query it's hard to find the right one sometimes in the docs

Comment: @hunterhacker I have a document with `<email>` as the element and contains `vikram@gmail.com` as its value. i am not able to get the value with the query being :

`cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("email"), "a")`

and the result being :

`cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("","email"), "a", ("lang=en"), 1)`

How to get the document and is there a **java API** replacement for this search.

Comment: Well, "a" isn't a word in that email address so no results is expected. You just want a wildcard type match? Try cts:element-value-match.